# Is it possible to debug "project in the project"

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I created two simple projects in Visual Studio. Then I connected them (file -> add -> existing project). Is it possible to debug one project in the second project?
(For example: I would like to create "debug button" in the first project, then click it and debug the second project. )

Answer (score 0):

When you want to debug your application from an active instance of another application, you will need an instance of Visual Studio to debug, so you could open `devenv` (the Visual Studio process) for debugging an executable.

You should use the `/debugexe` command line switch as explained on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241274.aspx).

Like this:

```
Process.Start( "C:\...\devenv.exe"
             , string.Format("/debugexe \"{0}\"", pathToSecondExecutable)
             );
```

Comment: @Eryk: Was this what you were looking for? Need more help?